# Editing single value in file in C efficiently

Tags: c, linux, file, sed

I have a C program that currently edits a single value in a parameter file by using sed through a system call.  I'd like to change the program to use the C file libraries to edit this value, but the only way I know how to do this is by reading in the entire file, changing the value, and rewriting the file.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?  The program is intended for use on an embedded device so I'd like to use the most efficient solution possible.

Comment: Open the file, move the cursor to the location, change and save. It works the same way as sed except it does not actually load the whole file.

Comment: Yes just open the file, use seek to place yourself at the value and then write the new one.

Comment: ...and if the new data is not the same length as the previous data...?

Comment: Well the data in this case happens to be the same length, but I imagine reading and rewriting the entire file is the only solution for data of a different size.

Comment: Technically, you could rewrite the *remainder* of the file instead of the whole file. But that becomes complicated. And for small files, I doubt it would be any faster.

Comment: @Weather Vane in this case, yes I always know exactly where in the file the data will be located.  But if there were variable length data occurring before it in the file, then a read would be necessary to locate the data to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with files is like working with arrays in the sense that one can't truly before insertions and deletions. Insertions and deletions require shifting (copying) the rest of the file/array. Only replacing elements is possible (by opening the file for reading and writing, and using `seek`).

Reading and writing the entire file is quite efficient, especially for tiny files. If the memory usage isn't an issue, that's the approach I would take.

Other solutions might be better in specific circumstances, but the approach you describe is generally the best.